# Getting error when installing basic requirements of transformers notebooks

Tags: python, nlp, google-colaboratory, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

I am working on a project and require some installation from transformers notebook this is the code which I ran google colab

```
!git clone https://github.com/nlp-with-transformers/notebooks.git

import os
os.chdir("/content/notebooks")


from install import *
install_requirements()
```

Below is the error:-

```
remote: Enumerating objects: 515, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (161/161), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (39/39), done.
remote: Total 515 (delta 139), reused 126 (delta 122), pack-reused 354
Receiving objects: 100% (515/515), 28.61 MiB | 16.21 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (246/246), done.
⏳ Installing base requirements ...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-926abb3f024d> in <cell line: 10>()
      8 
      9 from install import *
---> 10 install_requirements()

/content/notebooks/install.py in install_requirements(is_chapter2, is_chapter6, is_chapter7, is_chapter7_v2, is_chapter10, is_chapter11)
     29     process_install = subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
     30     if process_install.returncode != 0:
---> 31         raise Exception(" Failed to install base requirements")
     32     else:
     33         print("✅ Base requirements installed!")

Exception:  Failed to install base requirements
```

I have tried to separate the code lines but not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Update pip:

```
!pip install --upgrade pip
```

Then, run the installation code again.

or Install requirements manually In the install.py file, you can find a list of required packages under the variable requirements. You can install these packages individually by running `!pip install <package-name>`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which chapter you are reading, do this in Colab:

```
! pip install -r https://github.com/nlp-with-transformers/notebooks/blob/main/requirements.txt
```

And when you reach Chapter 7, you'll need this additionally:

```
! pip install -r https://github.com/nlp-with-transformers/notebooks/blob/main/requirements-chapter7-v2.txt
```